# Proving that $a+a=0 \implies a=0$ first with ordered field axioms and then only with field axioms??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have to prove that for $a \in \Bbb{R} $ , $a+a=0 \implies a=0$ first with all the following axioms, and then I'm asked if it is possible to prove it with only A.1) to A.9).

> A.1) If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers, then $a+(b+c) = (a+b)+c = a+b+c$
>
> A.2) If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then $a+b = b+a$
>
> A.3) There exists a real number $0$ such that for any real number $a$, the
>   following equality holds: $a+0 = a$
>
> A.4) For any real number $a$, there exists a real number $(-a)$ such that
>   $a+(-a) =0$
>
> A.5) If $a,b$ and $c$ are real numbers then $a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c=a*b*c$
>
> A.6) If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers then $a*b = b*a$
>
> A.7) There exists a real number $1$, $1 \ne 0 $, such that for any real
>   number $a$, the following equality holds: $a*1 = a$
>
> A.8) For any real number a different than $0$, $a \ne 0$, there exists a
>   real number $a^{-1}$ such that $a* a^{-1} = 1$
>
> A.9) If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers, then $a*(b+c) = a*b+a*c$
>
> A.10) For any real number $a$, $a=a$.
>
> A.11) If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, and $a = b$ then $b=a$
>
> A.12) If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers such that $a=b$ and $b=c$ then
>   $a=c$
>
> A.13) If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers, and $a=b$ then $a+c = b+c$
>
> A.14) If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers; and $a=b$ then $a*c = b*c$
>
> A.15) If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers then one and only one of the
>   following holds:
>
> - $a<b$
> - $a=b$
> - $b<a$
>
> A.16) If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers; $a<b$ and $b<c$ imply $a<c$
>
> A.17) If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers, $a<b$ implies $a+c<b+c$
>
> A.18) If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers; $a<b$ and $0<c$ imply $a*c<b*c$

I was able to do the first part (proof with all the axioms) but I'm not sure my proof is correct, so if anyone could check it I would appreciate it.

By A.15) $a \neq 0 \implies a>0 \text{ or } a<0$

- **Assuming $\mathbf{a>0}$:**

$a>0 \implies a+a > 0+a $   ***(A.17)***

$\implies a+a > a + 0$  ***(A.2)***

$\implies a+a > a$ ***(A.3)***

$\implies a+a > 0$ ***(A.16)***

- **Assuming $\mathbf{a<0}$:**

$a<0 \implies a+(-a)<0+(-a)$ ***(A.4 and A.17)***

$\implies 0 < (-a) + 0 $ ***(A.2 and A.4)***

$\implies 0<(-a)$ ***(A.3)***

$\implies 0+(-a)<(-a)+(-a)$ ***(A.4 and A.17)***

$\implies (-a)+0 < (-a)+(-a)$ ***(A.2)***

$\implies (-a)<(-a) + (-a)$ ***(A.3)***

$\implies  (-a) + a +a +a < (-a)+(-a) +a+a+a$ ***(A.17)***

$\implies a+a+a+(-a) < a+a+(-a)+a+(-a)$ ***(A.2)***

$\implies a+a+0<a+0+0$ ***(A.4)***

$\implies a+a<a$ ***(A.3)***

$\implies a+a<0$ ***(A.16)***

So $a \neq 0 \implies a+a \neq 0$ which is equivalent to $a+a = 0 \implies a=0$ . **Is this correct?**

**Can it be proven only with axioms A.1) to A.9)??**

Comment: Gonna be hard to prove with axioms A.1 to A.9, since there models where it isn't true.

Comment: Counter example. Let $F = \{0,1\}$ so that $0 + 0 = 0; 0+1=1+0= 1; 1+1 = 0; 0*x = 0; 1*x = x$.  That satisfies axiom A1 - A9.  $1+1 = 0$ but $1 \ne 0$.

Comment: in other words. A1 - A14 are the basic field axioms without order.  As there are *many* fields where $a + a = 0$ does not imply $a = 0$ you can not prove this without any of  the order axioms A15-A18.  I find it a little weird that they don't include the equality axioms A10-14.